# Why is LXDE displaying only boxes for font - and how to fix

Tags: fonts, character-encoding, lxde, x2go

A picture is worth 1000 words:

[image]

This is fedora 20 running LXDE using X2GOServer, with X2GO client on windows.  I am on a VPS at ramnode.

I assume it's an issue with encoding, but I just can't figure out how to fix it from the command line, and fixing it from the gui is practically impossible since I cant read anything.

Comment: Most likely you're missing some installed fonts. It's a brute-force solution, but doing `yum search fonts` and installing anything that seems likely might help.

Comment: I just installed XFCE and that works.  Should I delete the question - as now I have no real reason to try to find the answer?

Comment: There's no reason to delete the question; someone might come along and say something helpful, and the point of this place is to be a useful database for the future, as well.

Comment: Allright.  Should I write my workaround solution as an answer?

Comment: If desired. I'm not sure it would be on-topic, though.

Comment: Did the LXDE problem go away when installing XFCE, or is it just that XFCE works fine? In any case, you should investigate somewhat further and report it at [Fedora's bugzilla](http://bugzilla.redhat.com) (you'll probably need to create an account to report it, and to be able to comment on any developments/proposed fixes).

Comment: LXDE problem did not go away - I'm just using XFCE now.  Good idea about reporting the bug.

Answer (score 3):

On Arch Linux, install `ttf-dejavu`

Comment: Can you elaborate why installing this particular font will fix the problem, please.

Comment: The OP is on Fedora not Arch Linux.

Comment: This worked perfectly